# Nextjs 13: How to set serverside async component under client component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

is there any way to set async `Server Side Component` under `Client Side Component`?

```js
// Parent Client Side Component
"use client"

export function ParentCSC(){
 retun <ChildSSC/> // want to await or suspense here
}
```

```js
// Child Server Side Component
export async function ChildSSC(){
 const data = await ...
 return <div>{data}</div>
}
```

When I wrap child `Client Side Component` with `Suspense`, error occurs. Is there any way to solve this situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Per the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components), it's not possible to use a server-side component inside a client component, unless it's in `children`.

From their docs, it says that you ***can't*** do this:

```js
'use client';

// ❌ This pattern will not work. You cannot import a Server
// Component into a Client Component
import ServerComponent from './ServerComponent';

export default function ClientComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <ServerComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

but you can do this:

```js
// ✅ This pattern works. You can pass a Server Component
// as a child or prop of a Client Component.
import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import ServerComponent from "./ServerComponent";

// Pages are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: Updated link: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components

Comment: @verwirrt thanks, in the future please edit the post instead of commenting. [How/Why to Edit Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)